# startup receiver in android and keeping process always alive

Tags: android, android-service

I am new to android and I am working in a project.

What I need is to write a startup receiver, which when notified by android system should start a process. This process get the server date time by calling a restful service deployed in server and update two columns of a table.

This process should tick every second and I should make sure that this process is running all the time and android system shouldn't kill this process if its ever killed forcefully it should again restart.

How can I accomplish it? May you please provide some guide? I know how to consume a restful service and I can also write a startup receiver. The only thing I am confused is about how to make sure that the process is always running as long as android system is up.

Answer (score 0):

> ow to make sure that the process is always running as long as android system is up

There is no way to do that. System can kill your app when it finds that good idea. In most cases you will be restarted though. And it does not look like a good idea to consume RESTful service in always-on service. Consider using push messages (i.e. GCM) as trigger for your app

Comment: Ok I have no knowledge of it but I am googling on it

Comment: One thing I didnt understand is. You said if process is stopped it will be restarted is it true always

Comment: no. it may be restarted. it depends on why it was killed in the 1st place. but **usually** system restarts what it kills

Answer (score 0):

With only reciever cannot,  service can run contineously. so use one service which will be running contineously. Then start the service from the broadcast reciever.

Comment: Ok I missed that ya I will use service but if start new thread with a loop forever

Comment: ya you should do some thing like that. a countineous running thread but do it from service. please accept the ans and upvote its help full

Answer (score 0):

To prevent your service to be kill the only way is to start it in foreground. But with this method you'll have to define a notification which will be showed until your service is stopped.

Do like this in your method onStartCommand.

```
   NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(getResources().getString(R.string.foreground_not_text))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, LauncherActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

    not = builder.build();

    startForeground(Constants.NETWORK_NOT_ID, not);
return Service.START_STICKY;
```

Your application can still be killed by system but won't be the first app to be closed.

Comment: Ok but is there any way to restart the service automatically if stopped by Android system

Comment: I suppose that your service will go in onDestroy when he will be kill by the system. May be there is a way to detect when system close your service thanks to this method but I'm not sure.
Just to notify you, I use foreground pattern in several applications and I never saw my service be killed.